# Installed Gnome on Sputnik 16.04, not seeing what I am expecting

Tags: gnome

I have an XPS 13 running Project Sputnik Ubuntu 16.04. I am keen on running Gnome instead of the standard window manager, so I followed the following tutorial:

https://www.fossmint.com/install-gnome-3-20-in-ubuntu-16-04/

I was expecting to see something like this once I installed everything:
[image: Expected gnome desktop]

However, I'm seeing a very slightly modified desktop, as follows:

[image: What I'm seeing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the [Unity desktop environment](https://unity.ubuntu.com/), the environment that was pre-installed. To log in to the Gnome desktop environment, you must choose it at the time of login. To do so, click the Unity icon (see below) and choose Gnome.

[image: change desktop environment][image: change desktop environment]

You can also make Gnome the default desktop environment by editing the environment configuration in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` (for me it was `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`) and changing the line `user-session=unity` to `user-session=gnome`.

You could even uninstall Unity completely, with `sudo apt remove unity` (use `--purge` if you want to remove its configuration files), but when I did this, I still had to edit the configuration for lightdm to make it recognize Gnome as the default.

Comment: Thanks! I had to do both of these steps. I still have the unity logo against my login, all other logins have gnome; but upon logging in it just goes into Gnome.

Comment: Clicking on the ubuntu icon in lightdm hides the login box for a while, leaving me with nothing to click on.

Comment: @EmileVictor Even after you choose Gnome?

Comment: @EmileVictor Are you still having that problem? If so, could you describe in detail what you do to encounter it?